# Building a class hierarchy in Coq?

Tags: functional-programming, scope, typeclass, coq

I can naively construct a hierarchy of algebraic structures in Coq using type classes. I'm having some trouble finding resources on Coq's syntax and semantics for type classes. However, I believe the following is a correct implementation of semigroups, monoids and commutative monoids:

```
Class Semigroup {A : Type} (op : A -> A -> A) : Type := {
  op_associative : forall x y z : A, op x (op y z) = op (op x y) z
}.

Class Monoid `(M : Semigroup) (id : A) : Type := {
  id_ident_left  : forall x : A, op id x = x;
  id_ident_right : forall x : A, op x id = x
}.  

Class AbelianMonoid `(M : Monoid) : Type := {
  op_commutative : forall x y : A, op x y = op y x
}.
```

If I understand correctly, additional parameters (e.g., the identity element of a monoid) can be added by first declaring `Monoid` an instance of `Semigroup`, then parameterizing on `id : A`. However, something odd is occurring in the record constructed for `AbelianMonoid`.

```
< Print Monoid.
    Record Monoid (A : Type) (op : A -> A -> A) (M : Semigroup op) 
    (id : A) : Type := Build_Monoid
    { id_ident_left : forall x : A, op id x = x;
      id_ident_right : forall x : A, op x id = x }

< Print AbelianMonoid.
    Record AbelianMonoid (A : Type) (op : A -> A -> A) 
    (M0 : Semigroup op) (id0 : A) (M : Monoid M0 id0) : 
    Type := Build_AbelianMonoid
      { op_commutative : forall x y : A, op x y = op y x }
```

This occurred when I was trying to build a class for semigroups. I thought that the following syntax was correct:

```
Class Semiring `(P : AbelianMonoid) `(M : Monoid) := {
    ...
}.
```

However, I couldn't disambigutate the correct operators and identity elements. Printing the records revealed the problems outlined above. So I have two questions: first, how do I correctly declare the class `Monoid`; second, how do I disambiguate functions in superclasses?

What I'd really like is a good resources that clearly explains Coq's type classes without antiquated syntax. For example, I thought Hutton's book explained type classes in Haskell clearly.

Comment: If you're not doing this as a learning exercise, you might want to check out the math-classes library (which also might not have been around when you asked this) https://github.com/math-classes/math-classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**References:**

The canonical references for type classes in Coq - beyond [the manual](http://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual024.html) - are [this paper](http://mattam.org/research/publications/First-Class_Type_Classes.pdf), and [the thesis](http://mattam.org/research/PhD.en.html) (in french) of [Matthieu Sozeau](http://mattam.org/). There are less canonical references (with different points of view) at the research level in [a recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.1323), and in [my thesis](http://pastel.archives-ouvertes.fr/pastel-00649586).  You should also spend some time on the #coq channel on Freenode, and subscribe to [the mailing list](https://sympa-roc.inria.fr/wws/arc/coq-club).

**Your problem:**

The syntax issue is not with `Classes` per se, but with [maximally inserted](http://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual004.html#htoc53) [implicit arguments](http://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual004.html#toc20). The `Monoid` and `AbelianMonoid` *types* have in your definition (implicit) parametric arguments that are, in this order, the domain type, the operation, and the identity - as indexed by the dependent product that you see fully expanded when you print those record types. They are filled automatically when you mention the dependent product without its arguments in a position where it would need them.

Indeed, implicit argument resolution will automatically insert the required parametric arguments to be identical (for both products that depend on them : `P` and `M`'s types) if left to its own devices. You just need to specify constraints between those identifiers by specifying variables for the various identifiers, distinct when appropriate :

```
Class Semiring A mul add `(P : AbelianMonoid A mul) `(M : Monoid A add) := {
}.
```

The result :

```
> Print Semiring.
Record Semiring (A : Type) (mul add : A -> A -> A) 
(M0 : Semigroup mul) (id0 : A) (M : Monoid M0 id0) 
(P : AbelianMonoid M) (M1 : Semigroup add) (id1 : A) 
(M : Monoid M1 id1) : Type := Build_Semiring {  }

For Semiring: Arguments M0, id0, M, M1, id1 are implicit and maximally
              inserted
For Semiring: Argument scopes are [type_scope _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _]
For Build_Semiring: Argument scopes are [type_scope _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _]
```

Note the identities for the abelian monoid and monoid are this time distinct. It's a good exercise (even if it makes little mathematical sense) to train yourself to write the record type (aka the Class) you would want if you had the same identity element for the additive and multiplicative structures.

Comment: Thank you for the references to Sozeau and Oury. Their papers look helpful and informative, and are probably sufficient for now. I'm sure myself and others would benefit from your thesis if you feel like posting it once it reaches a finished state. Given your response, I feel that familiarizing myself more with dependent records would clarify Coq's implementation of type classes.