# Multiple Typeclass Inheritance in Coq

Tags: typeclass, coq

I've been trying to create a small typeclass hierarchy in Coq and I haven't been able to progress despite there being a few answers on stackoverflow that I thought would be the solution, particularly [Building a class hierarchy in Coq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990301/building-a-class-hierarchy-in-coq).

Here is what I have:

```
Class Unfoldable (C : Type -> Type) (A : Type)
  (insert : A -> C A -> C A)
  (empty : C A) : Type :=
{
  insert_neq : forall (x y : A) (h : C A),
    insert x h <> insert y h -> x <> y;
  empty_insert_eq : forall x y : A,
    insert x empty = insert y empty <-> x = y
}.

Class Foldable (C : Type -> Type) (A B : Type)
  (foldr : (A -> B -> B) -> B -> C A -> B) : Type :=
{
  (* Foldable properties??? *)
}.

Class Collection C A {B} insert empty foldr
  `{F : Foldable C A B foldr}
  `{U : Unfoldable C A insert empty} :=
{
  collection_id : forall h,
    foldr insert empty h = h
}.

Print Collection.
```

And here is the error message:

```
Error:
In environment
Collection :
forall (C : Type -> Type) (A B : Type) (insert : A -> C A -> C A)
  (empty : C A) (foldr : (A -> B -> B) -> B -> C A -> B),
Foldable C A B foldr -> Unfoldable C A insert empty -> Type
C : Type -> Type
A : Type
B : Type
insert : A -> C A -> C A
empty : C A
foldr : (A -> B -> B) -> B -> C A -> B
F : Foldable C A B foldr
U : Unfoldable C A insert empty
h : ?17
The term "insert" has type "A -> C A -> C A"
 while it is expected to have type "A -> B -> B".
```

Shouldn't `C A` have a type of `Type` and therefore fit as `B`?

Sorry about not being able to provide more information. I really don't know Coq well. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about type classes myself, but doesn't `B` need to be variable? By separating it from `foldr`, you're making it fixed. I think it only makes sense to make `C` and `A` fixed.

```
Class Foldable (C : Type -> Type) (A : Type)
  (foldr : forall B, (A -> B -> B) -> B -> C A -> B) : Type :=
{
  (* Foldable properties??? *)
}.

Class Collection C A insert empty foldr
  `{F : Foldable C A foldr}
  `{U : Unfoldable C A insert empty} :=
{
  collection_id : forall h, foldr (C A) insert empty h = h
}.
```

If you really want `B` fixed, you have to set it to `C A` because that's what `insert` and `empty` return, but you shouldn't want `B` to always be `C A`.

```
Class Collection C A insert empty foldr
  `{F : Foldable C A (C A) foldr}
  `{U : Unfoldable C A insert empty} :=
{
  collection_id : forall h, foldr insert empty h = h
}.
```

By the way, `insert_neq` is always provable.

```
Axiom C : Type -> Type.
Axiom A : Type.
Axiom empty : C A.
Axiom insert : A -> C A -> C A.

Goal forall (x y : A) (h : C A), insert x h <> insert y h -> x <> y.
intros ? ? ? H1 H2.
apply H1.
rewrite H2.
apply eq_refl.
Qed.
```

---

Update:

In your original code, you have something similar to the following.

```
Axiom C : Type -> Type.
Axiom A : Type.
Axiom B : Type.
Axiom insert : A -> C A -> C A.
Axiom empty : C A.
Axiom foldr : (A -> B -> B) -> B -> C A -> B.
(* Foldable properties??? *)
Axiom insert_neq : forall (x y : A) (h : C A), insert x h <> insert y h -> x <> y.
Axiom empty_insert_eq : forall x y : A, insert x empty = insert y empty <-> x = y.

Axiom collection_id : forall h : C A, foldr insert empty h = h.
```

This last axiom is ill-typed because `foldr` returns a `B`, not a `C A`. There are no guarantees that they can be the same thing.

Unless `B` has any particular properties, you can just make `foldr` polymorphic.

```
Axiom C : Type -> Type.
Axiom A : Type.
Axiom insert : A -> C A -> C A.
Axiom empty : C A.
Axiom foldr : forall B : Type, (A -> B -> B) -> B -> C A -> B.
(* Foldable properties??? *)
Axiom insert_neq : forall (x y : A) (h : C A), insert x h <> insert y h -> x <> y.
Axiom empty_insert_eq : forall x y : A, insert x empty = insert y empty <-> x = y.

Axiom collection_id : forall h : C A, foldr (C A) insert empty h = h.
```

In this case, `foldr` takes an extra argument: the type it returns. The equivalent to the Haskell type `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`, in Coq, is `forall a b : Type, (a -> b -> b) -> b -> list a -> b`.

The second example I gave is equivalent to the following.

```
Axiom C : Type -> Type.
Axiom A : Type.
Axiom insert : A -> C A -> C A.
Axiom empty : C A.
Axiom foldr : (A -> C A -> C A) -> C A -> C A -> C A.
(* Foldable properties??? *)
Axiom insert_neq : forall (x y : A) (h : C A), insert x h <> insert y h -> x <> y.
Axiom empty_insert_eq : forall x y : A, insert x empty = insert y empty <-> x = y.

Axiom collection_id : forall h : C A, foldr insert empty h = h.
```

Comment: Thanks, changing `foldr` and `collection_id` seems to have solved my problem, though, at first, I didn't notice the change to `collection_id`. Can you explain what adding `(C A)` means? I don't see how fits syntactically with the property.

Comment: This update really helped. So even instead of a function being polymorphic like in Haskell, Coq just makes the function require a type input in addition to its normal input. Does that mean that I defined the classes wrong? I should remove the `A` from the class definition and add a `forall A : Type,` to all the functions, correct?

Comment: @user2063685 Normally, you can just mark type arguments as implicit and let Coq automatically infer them for you, but that doesn't work for arguments of type classes. Unless the type `A` has any properties you're trying to capture, like `C` does, I don't think you really win anything by making `A` fixed.